# JS (or Jquery) on demand div gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am searching for a really simple (div) gallery, so I am asking this question here because galleries (sliders mostly) on a Internet are full of unnecessary features/codes.

Its really simple what I need. One main div (to show big image & text) and another set of divs (list - where I can gather thumbnails with text) to see whats in the database.

Simply everything to work with on-demand click. Click on a list div - show on main (big) div, and so on.

Any ideas where to start?

ps: I havent tried anything because Im new to jquery and need some pinpoints. Any ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use ResponsiveSlides.js, it has only jQuery as depency, **1kb minified and gzipped**

**Features**

Fully responsive

- 1kb minified and gzipped
- CSS3 transitions with JavaScript fallback
- Simple markup using unordered list
- Settings for transition and timeout durations
- Multiple slideshows supported
- Automatic and manual fade
- Works in all major desktop and mobile browsers
- Captions and other html-elements supported inside slides
- Separate pagination and next/prev controls
- Possibility to choose where the controls append to
- Possibility to randomize the order of the slides
- Possibility to use custom markup for pagination
- Can be paused while hovering slideshow and/or controls
- Images can be wrapped inside links
- Optional 'before' and 'after' callbacks

Usage samples can be found on: http://responsiveslides.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx FelipeKM seems this one will do! Finally something normal, thax!!! :))

Comment: Hey Felipe, maybe you know some quick code addon for this slider to go next upon clicking on a big image (id=wrapper) in slideshow1? Thx. Joem

Comment: I suggest you to go through Github: https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js download the demo samples, it's very simple